# Angular, how to use directive based on an boolean

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

I use a `ngFor` to show different `button`. I need to use a directive on different button but not all.

So I make this code :

```
<div *ngFor="let btn of btns">
  <button {{ btn.useDirective ? 'appMyDirective' : '' }} ></button>
</div>
```

But I get this error

> Error: Template parse errors:
>   Unexpected closing tag "button". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag.

Comment: send an input to the directive, if the condition matches then do what the directive does otherwise leave it. Don't add two buttons based on condition.

Comment: @MuruGan I use a directive already used by other components. It's possible to add a condition without bad effect on other components using the same directive ?

Comment: Yes u can. like below answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update you directive to be trigger base on state as an example consider this

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appHello]'
})
export class HelloDirective {

    @Input() appHello:boolean;

    constructor(private elem: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      if (this.appHello !== false ) {
         this.renderer.setProperty(this.elem.nativeElement, 'innerHTML', 'Hi ');
      }
    }

}
```

template

```
<div *ngFor="let btn of btns">
  <button [appHello]="btn.useDirective">Hi </button>
</div>
```

if you set the value to be true the directive will work otherwise nothing will happen

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d2j8sn)

Comment: I try, but that have no effect, the directive is not applied

Comment: Since he already uses the directive in other places, without the condition, I think that you should set the default `@Input` value to `true`.

Comment: After experimenting with [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nyy9ex?file=src/app/highlight.directive.ts), it appears that the condition has to be set to `if (this.appHello !== false) { ... }` in order to work. The default value is not used, probably because the `@Input` is associated with the directive name. The value is set to `undefined` (or an empty string) when no value is supplied.

Comment: Normally, I would have used you current code `if (this.appHello)` but, since the default value is empty (which is falsy), I think you have to test against `false` if you want the directive to be applied by default.

Comment: @ConnorsFan  thanks for the feedback , I have test too `!== false` is the correct one so by default the directive will apply

Comment: Note, I use this syntax `@Input('appHello') public useDirective:boolean;` instead, because I have an error `Can't bind to 'appHello' since it isn't a known property of 'button'` with your syntax

Comment: @Kamoulox in my example I have made the selector and property as the same that will make it work as  `<button appHello` so you need to update your directive like this  

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is invalid. To archieve what you want, do something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let btn of btns">
  <button *ngIf="btn.useDirective" appMyDirective></button>
  <button *ngIf="!btn.useDirective"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: There are no better solution ? I have many property/class/event on the btn. And I think it's very ugly to create two different tag and switch with ngIf...

Comment: Yes, you can create an directive that extends the original directive and accept a boolean as value.

Answer (score 1):

Try using below instead.

```
<div *ngFor="let btn of btns">
  <button appMyDirective *ngIf="btn.useDirective"></button>
  <button *ngIf="!btn.useDirective"></button>
</div>
```